# Passing GUID value through SqlQuery will raise the error: invalid input syntax for type uuid

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I wrote code to call a function from PostgreSQL. In the pgAdmin, I call the function and it works fine.

This is my code in C#:

```
_db.Database.SqlQuery<CreateOrderInfo>($"select * from Asset_CreateOrderInfo('{request.Data!.UserId}',{request.Data!.SymbolId})")
```

The generated command is like this:

```
select * from Asset_CreateOrderInfo('00000001-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',2)
```

When I run the above code in the pgAdmin, it works right. But when I send through the EF Core and C#, It doesn't work and raises this error:

> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 22P02: invalid input syntax for type uuid: "@p0"

Could you help me understand what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution myself. I removed the single quote around the '{request.Data!.UserId}' and it worked fine.

```
_db.Database.SqlQuery<CreateOrderInfo>($"select * from Asset_CreateOrderInfo({request.Data!.UserId},{request.Data!.SymbolId})")
```

It was really a ridiculous problem!!!